# react native android hide or disable keyboard permanently for kiosk app

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, show-hide, dismiss

I need to disable or hide the keyboard in my app which is a kiosk mode app.
I googled it and did not find way to hide keyboard for the whole app without losing focus of the input (since I will be using external keyboard).

I also want to have the ability to show the keyboard for maintenance by clicking on button or something.

Any one who can help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file under your activity use:

```
<activity ... android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

and then in your oncreate event create an ontouchlistener :

```
MyEdittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View MyView, MotionEvent event) {
    MyView.onTouchEvent(event);
    InputMethodManager inputMethod = (InputMethodManager)MyView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethod!= null) {
        inputMethod.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MyView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }                
    return true;
}
```

});

and to re-enable the keyboard just add this to the item of the xml you want to enable :

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks for your response, the issue is that i'm developing with react native, so I can not have access to my input instance like you showed above.